# How to add text to image in java?

Tags: java, image, text, graphics, image-editing

I am using Prime-faces. Here i need to add dynamic text to bottom of the image using java.
i.e, I need to "write" on the image and I need to save image with text in my desired PC location.

I have tried this:

```
public void writeToImage() throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        final BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new URL(
                "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png"));

        Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
        g.setFont(g.getFont().deriveFont(30f));
        g.drawString("Hello World!", 100, 100);
        g.dispose();

        ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("test.png"));
    }
```

How do I achieve it?

Comment: By first telling us more, including what GUI library you might be using -- Swing? Android? SWT? Something else? Then what have you tried and where are you stuck? Please give us the important details that might allow your question to be answered without guessing.

Comment: *"How to add text to small image?"*  The same way you might add text to a large image, but smaller (the text length/font size smaller).  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Sorry. Will do from next time @Hovercraft Full Of Eels

Comment: How about consider still doing it for *this* time. Please edit your question and add the information. Is this a Swing application?

Comment: no. Its not. Just did it.

Comment: I trying to save that image. How do i do it?

Comment: Again, what GUI library are you using?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels *"Again, what GUI library are you using?"* Huh?  Given this can be done using AWT/`ImageIO` in a command line app., I do not understand your question.  But then, I also don't understand why the OP is still confused, given they put code that will do it, in the question.

Comment: BTW - Lenna.png is 463 Kb!  Can't you find a smaller(1) image to link to?  1) E.G. < 50 Kb.  An alternative might be to generate an image in code, like `new BufferedImage(200,50,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);`

Answer (score 0):

You can draw on a BufferedImage using the the Graphics object:

```
Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
g.drawString("hello", x, y);
```

Comment: 1) Don't forget to `g.dispose()` 2) Given it is a 'small image', it would pay to take into account the `FontMetrics` or `GlyphVector` of the text being drawn.

Answer (score 0):

you have code for insert txt file to images?

sample file insert.txt content

1. Cobra
2. Anaconda
3. Phyton
4. Comodo

Note.
Wildlife of Amazon

Comment: Are you answering the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17771677/how-to-add-text-to-image-in-java) or asking a different question?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please consider reading this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer#:~:text=Read%20the%20question%20carefully&text=Your%20answer%20can%20say%20%E2%80%9Cdon,going%20in%20the%20right%20direction.) on how to write answers and help the community.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).